# Factoring a quadratic residue modulo

Tags: algorithms

Do apologize, wasn't sure where to ask this, but I was wondering how an algorithm would factor and show the square roots in a quadratic residue modolo when you're given $N$ and $a$, which is a quadrtic residue modulo $N$.

Comment: Is the number $N$ prime?  Then there are good algorithms, see e.g. Shanks-Tonelli.

Comment: The title "Factoring a quadratic residue modulo" is a bit jarring, especially given that the actual problem seems to be finding square roots of $a \in \mathbb{Z}_N$.  See this [recent Answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/932570/3111) for finding four square roots when $N$ is the product of two distinct odd primes.